# Binomial Formula evaluation for the problem $9 \mid 10^k - 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> Prove using binomial formula $9 \mid 10^k - 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

I am aware of similar answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870066/why-is-10k-1-divisible-by-9/1870069) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497235/how-to-show-that-10n-1-is-divisible-by-9/497238) however my query is about the manipulation on the binomial formula in my proof.

My attempt at the proof :

We notice that $$10^k - 1 = (9 + 1)^k - 1$$ $$=\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{k} {k \choose i} 9^{k-i} \right) - 1$$

How do I further remove the -1 to show that this indeed is divisible by 9 ?

Comment: Every term in the summation but the last is a multiple of $9$ and the last term in the summation is equal to $1$ itself and cancels with the $-1$ outside of the summation.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz pls write this comment as answer so that OP can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really remove the $-1$, but don't need to:   one of the terms in the sum is $1$, cancelling with the  $-1$.  The rest are divisible by  $9$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{k} {k \choose i} 9^{k-i} \right) - 1=$$
$$=\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} {k \choose i} 9^{k-i}+ {k \choose k} 9^{k-k} - 1$$

How much is ${k \choose k} 9^{k-k}$?

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).